# Why does Ecto have a maintenance_database option?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I was recently looking through the docs of [Ecto Postgres Adapter](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.html) and noticed it had an option for `maintenance_database`. It says it's the database used when dropping or creating the db. But why would it need this because at the time of dropping or creating the database you would be using a mix task most of the time and it would be a controller at that point so it wouldn't be a using a persisted connection to connected to the db anyway?

I was just baffled by this option because it just seems odd and I was wondering if someone could shed some light on how to use it in a practical way and maybe why it would exist.

If this is the wrong medium for asking these sort of discussion questions then let me know and I'll move it to another location.

Comment: There might be some internal cases when you need to drop the connection and to avoid errors this mechanism was implemented as a workaround, since the pool is always connected to the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mix` is not included in releases, in the first place. Imagine the case when you maintain the mission-critical software that cannot be shut down for a nanosecond. Now there is a need to clean up the database for, say, performance reasons.

The simplest (and fastest) way would be to drop and create the DB. So you instruct your supervision tree to understand this option via [`GenServer.code_change/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/GenServer.html#c:code_change/3) callbacks *and* deploy the code that performs an action.

Also, I doubt I follow what *controller* do you mention in the question, [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) applications do not require [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) at all to run.